# How to delete an entire line in Toad?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I'm starting to use Toad 11.0 a lot more, and I've spent a half hour searching online for a keyboard shortcut to delete an entire line of sql in the editor window. I don't want to have to highlight the line, I just want to delete the line my cursor is on. This functionality exists in many other apps, and is usually a shortcut such as:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (notepad++)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> (visual studio)
  etc.

(Those keystrokes don't work in Toad.)

There must be a way. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it. It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. Nice that I found it, but that's a strange, lame, and uncommon way to map line deletions.

I went into the Key Mapping screen of Toad and tried to change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, but that didn't work.

Comment: Uncommon? Depends how long you've been using computers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Y.  WordStar FTW ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.  Referenced in [Toad for MySQL blog](http://toadformysql.com/entry.jspa?categoryID=501&externalID=4724).

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+DELETE does nothing. I just tried it. Any other ideas?